# Prevent absolutely-positioned elements from overlapping with text

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a unique situation here.

Essentially, I have an absolutely positioned block of text, which must be absolutely positioned due to design limitations.

I also have the rest of my text, which is normally positioned. However, I need to prevent my normal text from overlapping with my original text.

Is this possible simply with HTML and inline CSS? I do not have access to JavaScript or external/`head`-related CSS; only inline styles are available. I have created a simplified version of my CSS with [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VKYwD/1/).

Comment: Is the height of the absolutely positioned text fixed?

Comment: It's definitely possible, but because of the nature of absolute positioning, will take extra work. In the jsfiddle example, how should that overlap be prevented? Are you hoping for some sort of word wrap around the absolutely-positioned block?

Comment: Unless you know the exact dimensions of your absolutely positioned `div`, I don't think there's a way with your limitations. Are the dimensions known?

Comment: @thirtydot Width is 541px, height is 34px, if that matters.

Comment: @mc10: @Steve Bennett is already doing what I was thinking: http://jsfiddle.net/VKYwD/10/ - although, that doesn't make much sense: why can't you just remove `position: absolute` from the `div`? I don't think I'm understanding this properly..

Comment: @thirtydot This is on a wiki, and I don't have access to the CSS files included, so I have to work with predefined ids and classes, which use absolute positioning.

Comment: @mc10: You can remove absolute positioning from an element by using `position: static`. Your inline styles will override anything in the "CSS files included" (let's forget about `!important`).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Is a solution to create another div (div2) that overlaps the absolutely positioned div (div1), but is itself invisible? Then the rest of the text would avoid overlapping div2...

Sketched this out here: http://jsfiddle.net/VKYwD/8/

Not entirely clear on what your constraints are though.

Comment: That seems interesting; can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Does the new element have to be _exactly_ the size of the absolutely-positioned element?

Comment: Width is 541px, height is 34px, though this may vary as I add more text into the absolutely-positioned element, so it would be best for the solution to be able to adapt to different widths and heights that I can manually put into the `<div>`.

Comment: well, the new element has to be "at least as big" as the absolutely positioned one. just think of it like putting a piece of clear plastic down on the ground to stop people walking through your artwork. if it's too small, it's not protecting it. if it's too big, that's ok.

Comment: What about when you need to place the absolutely positioned element at the bottom of the text?

Comment: Not pretty, I did a version that uses a wrapper and a pseudo-element, see (http://jsfiddle.net/429to664/) basically you write `<div class=wrapper><div class=absolutish>...</div></div>`