# Stop absolutely positioned div from overlapping text

Tags: html, css

Here is a simplification of my layout:

```html
    <div style="position: relative; width:600px;">
        <p>Content of unknown length, but quite quite quite quite quite quite quite quite quite quite quite quite quite quite quite quite long</p>
        <div>Content of unknown height</div>
        <div class="btn" style="position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0; width: 200px; height: 100px;background-color: red;"></div>
    </div>
```

The problem I'm having is that if the text/unknown div content is too long it is overlapping my absolutely positioned div.

I have searched the web and SO for a solution and the only one I found suggested putting an invisible div where absolutely positioned div is - trouble is if I could do that I wouldn't need to have the absolutely positioned div in the first place (or am I missing the point here).

Can anyone think of a css solution before I go down the jquery route?

Comment: Demonstrate your problem on jsFiddle. I copy-pasted your example (also added dimensions and background to .btn) and the long content doesn't seem to 'overlap' the button http://jsfiddle.net/gzSGM/

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The solution for me was to create a second invisible div at the end of the content of unknown length, this invisible div is the same size as my absolutely positioned div, this ensures that there is always a space at the end of my content for the absolutely positioned div.

This answer was previously provided here:
[Prevent absolutely-positioned elements from overlapping with text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301719/prevent-absolutely-positioned-elements-from-overlapping-with-text)
However I didn't see (until now) how to apply it to a bottom right positioned div.

New structure is as follows:

```html
<div id="outer" style="position: relative; width:450px; background-color:yellow;">
        <p>Content of unknown length</p>
        <div>Content of unknown height </div>
        <div id="spacer" style="width: 200px; height: 25px; margin-right:0px;"></div>
        <div style="position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0px; width: 200px; height: 20px; background-color:red;">bottom right</div>
    </div>
```

This seems to solve the issue.

Comment: How does it solve the problem you described?  Did you leave out some code?  http://jsbin.com/vadiwakuvuzu/1/edit

Comment: 2 years on I can honestly say I have not a clue

Comment: no worries, I just got a notification on this question now, guess I am a link in a necro-chain

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you so much! The `position:absolute; right:x;` divs are a challenge sometimes. I wish I'd seen this an hour ago.

Answer (score 14):

**Short answer:** There's no way to do it using CSS only.

**Long(er) answer:** Why? Because when you do `position: absolute;`, that takes your element out of the document's regular flow, so there's no way for the text to have any positional-relationship with it, unfortunately.

One of the possible alternatives is to `float: right;` your `div`, but if that doesn't achieve what you want, you'll have to use JavaScript/jQuery, or just come up with a better layout.

Comment: as @Chris said float is the best option:

`.foo{
float: right;
display: inline-block;
}`

Answer (score 8):

If you are working with elements of unknown size, and you want to use `position: absolute` on them or their siblings, you're inevitably going to have to deal with overlap.  By setting absolute position you're removing the element from the document flow, but the behaviour you want is that your element should be be pushed around by its siblings so as not to overlap...ie it should flow!  You're seeking two totally contradictory things.

You should rethink your layout.

Perhaps what you want is that the `.btn` element should be absolutely positioned with respect to one of its preceding siblings, rather than against their common parent?  In that case, you should set `position: relative` on the element you'd like to position the button against, and then make the button a child of that element.  Now you can use absolute positioning and control overlap.

Comment: I found this documentation, with some visualisation that help me understand this great answer :
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_without_z-index

Answer (score 7):

Put a `z-index` of `-1` on your absolute (or relative) positioned element.

This will pull it out of the stacking context. (I think.) Read more things about "stacking contexts" here: https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Comment: Sorry, it's been nearly 3 years, but how does removing an element from the stacking context add it to the document flow?

Answer (score 3):

Thing which works for me is to use padding-bottom on the sibling just before the absolutely-positioned child. Like in your case, it will be like this:

```
<div style="position: relative; width:600px;">
    <p>Content of unknown length, but quite quite quite quite quite quite quite quite quite quite quite quite quite quite quite quite long</p>
    <div style="padding-bottom: 100px;">Content of unknown height</div>
    <div class="btn" style="position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0; width: 200px; height: 100px;background-color: red;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
<div style="position: relative; width:600px;">
        <p>Content of unknown length</p>
        <div>Content of unknown height</div>
        <div id="spacer" style="width: 200px; height: 100px; float:left; display:inline-block"></div>
        <div class="btn" style="position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0; width: 200px; height: 100px;"></div>
    </div>
```

This should be a comment but I don't have enough reputation yet. The solution works, but visual studio code told me the following putting it into a css sheet:

> inline-block is ignored due to the float. If 'float' has a value other than 'none', the box is floated and 'display' is treated as 'block'

So I did it like this

```
.spacer {
    float: left;
    height: 20px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

And it works just as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should set `z-index` to absolutely positioned div that is greater than to relative div.

Something like that

```
<div style="position: relative; width:600px; z-index: 10;">
    <p>Content of unknown length</p>
    <div>Content of unknown height</div>
    <div class="btn" style="position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0; width: 200px; height: 100px; z-index: 20;"></div>
</div>
```

`z-index` sets *layers* positioning in *depth* of page.

Or you may use floating to show all text of unkown length. But in this case you could not absolutely position your `div`

```
<div style="position: relative; width:600px;">
  <div class="btn" style="float: right; width: 200px; height: 100px;"></div>
  <p>Content of unknown length Content of unknown length Content of unknown length Content of unknown length Content of unknown length Content of unknown length Content of unknown length Content of unknown length</p>
  <div>Content of unknown height</div>
  <div class="btn" style="position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0; width: 200px; height: 100px;"></div>
</div>​
```

Comment: I believe the OP's point is that the text should wrap around the absolutely-positioned `div`.

Comment: Oh, may be. Extended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm responding because I also ended up in this post and found a simple and effective solution: the absolute element has a fixed position and size, so you simply need to add right padding of 400px (referring to your example) to your content

Answer (score -2):

put texts into a new div. Then make that div also `position: absolute;` . Also, you can use `overflow: hidden;` for that div.

Comment: This wouldn't work as in the question it is mentioned that the text is of unknown length.