# Absolute Position div not pushing other content down

Tags: html, css

Most of my code in a jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/suxWt/

The content should load on the first page in a white box, with overflowing content pushing the following sections of the page down. However, as can be seen the lower sections load over the top of the first page white box. I have tried changing the positioning/clears of the various sections but cannot seem to create the necessary movement.

```
<section class="page1">
<div class="huge-title centered">  
    <div id='detailsbox'>
    <h1 id='eorvtitle'></h1>
    <img id='eorvimage' src=''>
        <div><p>lots of text lots of text                   
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="page2" id='page2'>
</section>

.page1 { 
    background: url('../img/bg.jpg')#131313;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.huge-title {
    position: absolute;
    top: -20%;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 180px;
}
#detailsbox {
    top: -4em;
    width: 75%;
    left: 12.5%;
    right: 12.5%;
    border: 20px solid white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS here instead of linking to your website, for now and for future reference.

Comment: I linked the website here as I am unable to isolate the problem down to a few lines. I feel the complexity requires more sections of the HTML/CSS/JS

Comment: set `z-index` to something like 999

Comment: Solved...look at my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to change `.huge-title` and `#detailsbox` to `position:relative;`
you can probably get rid of `background-size: cover;`
also change `.huge-title` and `#detailsbox` to the following:

```
.page1 {
  background: url('../img/bg.jpg')#131313;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.huge-title {
  position: relative;
  top: 20%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
#detailsbox {
  top: -4em;
  width: 75%;
  left: 12.5%;
  right: 12.5%;
  border: 20px solid white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: That's wacked!  My fiddle somehow got hacked or something.  In my jsfiddle account it is now marked as spam and the code was replaced with `(function(i){var e=/iPhone/i,n=/iPod/i,o=/iPad/i,t=/(?=.*\bAndroid\b)(?=.*\bMobile`

Answer (score 14):

Absolute Positioning does not push containers down. It places itself above or below them based on the z-indexing. You need to enclose your absolute contents inside a relative container to push other containers downwards similar to those in jquery sliders.

Answer (score 6):

The proper function of an absolute position is to overlap content. If you want other content to automatically push down then use `relative` position.

Comment: Setting the `#detailsbox` to `position: relative` still leaves the same issue

Comment: @user3608238 While Joseph's answer isn't the best, the point stands that `position: absolute;` removes an element from the regular content flow. It's as if your website is on one plane of existence, and the absolute positioned element is floating above it.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to create an empty spacer div with float right or left. This would ensure there is space between the two.
[Refer this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12357242/stop-absolutely-positioned-div-from-overlapping-text)

Answer (score 1):

Absolute positioned elements are removed from the main flow of the HTML. That's why it's not pushing the elements below it down. It's now sitting on top of the elements before and after it rather than in between them.

You may want to [check this out](http://designshack.net/articles/css/the-lowdown-on-absolute-vs-relative-positioning/).

Whether or not absolute positioning makes sense in your case is hard to say without seeing the design you are trying to implement. Using default (aka "static") or perhaps relative positioning will push the other content down below the white box, but without a deign to look at it's hard to tell if that's the real solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can add another empty section between page1 and page2 and give the css below

**height: 100%;**

Answer (score 0):

Adding an empty div the size of the absolute entity between the absolute entity and other components may help.