# Relative-positioned section appears in strange place

Tags: html, css, css-position, display

This is laughably basic, but I'm struggling with the placement of a relative-positioned div.

I have an absolute header that's 100vh tall containing a headline and caption, followed by two section elements, both of which are relative. The first has a "top" value of 100vh, putting it immediately below the header. The second I assumed would simply follow the first, but instead it attaches itself to the header caption.

I've distilled the page down into a snippet to demonstrate the problem.

```css
/* -------------------- UNIVERSAL TYPES -------------------- */

section {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 40px 0;
}

/* -------------------- HEADER  -------------------- */

header {
 position: absolute;
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100%;
 background: #111111;
 top: 0;
}

header .content {
 width: auto;
 max-width: 500px;
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: 40vh;
 text-align: center;
 color: #ffffff;
}

header .content .headline {
 font-size: 100px;
 margin-bottom: 0px
    height:100px;
 margin-bottom: 20px
}

header .content .caption {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 font-size: 20px;
}

/* -------------------- UNIVERSAL CONTENT -------------------- */

.pagecontent {
 position: relative;
 width: 1000px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 30px;
}

.pagecontent h2 {
 font-size: 80px;
}

.pagecontent p {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 20px;
}

/* -------------------- INDIVIDUAL SECTIONS -------------------- */

#About {
 top: 100vh;
 background-color: #CCC;
 color: #333333;
}

#Portfolio {
 background-color: #333;
 color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@0.6.2/build/pure-min.css" integrity="sha384-UQiGfs9ICog+LwheBSRCt1o5cbyKIHbwjWscjemyBMT9YCUMZffs6UqUTd0hObXD" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="headline">Header.</div>
      <div class="caption">Caption on dark background. This header section is 100vh tall and positioned absolutely.</div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <section id="About">
    <div class="pagecontent">
      <h2> About section header </h2>
      <p>All subsequent sections, starting with this one, are relative. My problem is that this section is obscured by the "Portfolio" section, which refuses to add on to the end of the page, and instead inserts itself immediately following the header caption. Duis aliquam finibus sagittis.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="Portfolio">
    <div class="pagecontent">
      <h2>Portfolio section header.</h2>
      <p>This section refuses to add on to the end of the page, and instead inserts itself immediately following the header caption.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Again, I know this probably has a very simple solution (I'm still quite new to modern CSS), but I've been scratching my head for ages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Absolute Position div not pushing other content down](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23999810/absolute-position-div-not-pushing-other-content-down)

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `position: absolute` property removes the content from main-flow of the default rendering and places where you position it. And just due to this reason, the second element doesn't recognizes previous element and starts from original location.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
}

header {
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<header>This is absolute</header>
<section>This is Relative but aligned by giving TOP: 200px<br>Just to tell where RED DIV ends</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. the `.content` is absolute, meaning it has been removed from the document flow, making other element cover or go behind it

```
body {
    padding-top: 100vh;
}
#About {
    background-color: green;
    color: #333333;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Relative elements are at their original point of origin. The header and sections are siblings. The header is absolute so isn't there as far as other elements are concerned. The first section would normally occupy the space the header occupies but it was moved down 100vh. The second section is given no direction to go so it stays at the place it originally occupies which is at the end of the first section *before it was moved 100vh*. So if you assign the second section `top` with the value of the height of the first section, it should behave as you wanted it to.

But if you have siblings you should position them all the same and wrap them in a positioned element. In the Snippet I have made the most commonly used type consisting of a relative parent and absolute children. Absolute will reference itself to the closest positioned element. So if that closest positioned element happens to be it's parent, then it will reference itself to the edges of said parent.

- Wrap everything in a container and give it `position:relative` [`<main>`]
- Give the immediate descendants (i.e. children) `position: absolute` [`<section>` and `<header>`]
- Give them each a height [`section, header {height:100vh}`]
- Give the header `top:0` (which you did)
- Assign the first section `top:{HEIGHT OF HEADER}` (which you did) [`top:100vh`]
- The second section should have `top:{HEIGHT OF HEADER + HEIGHT OF 1ST SECTION}` or if the child is `relative` then `top:{HEIGHT OF 1st SECTION}` (which you didn't do)[`top:200vh`]

**SNIPPET**(outlines and transparent backgrounds for demo)

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font: 400 16px/1.5 Verdana;
  overflow: scroll;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}


/* -------------------- UNIVERSAL TYPES -------------------- */

section {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 40px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  outline: 8px solid blue;
}

main {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
  outline: 10px solid gold;
}


/* -------------------- HEADER  -------------------- */

header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(20, 20, 20, .1);
  top: 0;
  outline: 5px dashed gold;
  height: 100vh;
}

header .content {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*margin-top: 40vh;*/
  text-align: center;
  color: tomato;
  outline: 3px dotted red;
}

header .content .headline {
  font-size: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 0px height:100px;
  /*margin-bottom: 20px;*/
  outline: 3px dotted blue;
}

header .content .caption {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 20px;
  outline: 3px dotted green;
}


/* -------------------- UNIVERSAL CONTENT -------------------- */

.pagecontent {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 30px;
  outline: 5px dashed brown;
}

.pagecontent h2 {
  font-size: 80px;
  outline: 5px dotted cyan;
}

.pagecontent p {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 20px;
  outline: 3px solid lime
}


/* -------------------- INDIVIDUAL SECTIONS -------------------- */

#About {
  top: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(111, 111, 111, .1);
  color: #ff0000;
  outline: 5px solid red;
}

#Portfolio {
  top: 200vh;
  background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, .1);
  color: purple;
  outline: 5px double purple;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@0.6.2/build/pure-min.css" integrity="sha384-UQiGfs9ICog+LwheBSRCt1o5cbyKIHbwjWscjemyBMT9YCUMZffs6UqUTd0hObXD" crossorigin="anonymous">-->
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <header>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="headline">Header.</div>
        <div class="caption">Caption on dark background. This header section is 100vh tall and positioned absolutely.</div>
      </div>
    </header>

    <section id="About">
      <div class="pagecontent">
        <h2> About section header </h2>
        <p>All subsequent sections, starting with this one, are relative. My problem is that this section is obscured by the "Portfolio" section, which refuses to add on to the end of the page, and instead inserts itself immediately following the header
          caption. Duis aliquam finibus sagittis.</p>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section id="Portfolio">
      <div class="pagecontent">
        <h2>Portfolio section header.</h2>
        <p>This section refuses to add on to the end of the page, and instead inserts itself immediately following the header caption.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>
```