# Make absolutely positioned element break scrollable text

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a text box that renders text. This text box has a max height and its overflow is set to `auto` which makes it scrollable. Now I want to introduce a checkbox that renders on the bottom right of this text box. To make this happen I positioned the checkbox absolutely at the bottom right. This already works as expected:

[image: checkbox showing at the bottom right]

Now comes my question: Is it possible to make the text break around the checkbox so the text is prevented from being hidden by the checkbox?

This has to be achieved at the same time while still making sure that the checkbox doesn't move when the text is being scrolled and it should stay (at least visually) inside the text box.

I already tried using flex layout and grid layout approaches that either failed because the check box moved during scrolling or the checkbox uses additional space outside of the text box which I don't want to happen.

There is also a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12357242/stop-absolutely-positioned-div-from-overlapping-text) that got a solution but in that question the text is not scrollable so it is possible to add an invisible spacer into the scrollable text box that breaks the text. This solution does not work here because we don't know where to add the spacer, because depending on the scrolling position it has to be in different places.

My current version where text runs below the checkbox (which is unwanted) can be found in this fiddle:

```css
.text {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  max-height: 8em;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.read {
  display: inline;
  padding: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -2px;
  right: 36px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="text">
    Hello World Hello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello World Hello World Hello World Hello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello World Hello World Hello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello World Hello World Hello
    World Hello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello World Hello World Hello World Hello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello World Hello World HelloWorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello World Hello World Hello
    World Hello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello World Hello World Hello World Hello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello World Hello World HelloWorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello World Hello World Hello
    World Hello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello World Hello World Hello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello World Hello World Hello World HelloWorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello World Hello World Hello
    World
  </div>
  <div class="read" id="read">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <label for="read">Read</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the closest to the requirement that I could do. This involves a `float: right` on the checkbox and a `scroll` event handler on the wrapper that adjusts the checkbox position.

The checkbox needs to be on top in this solution so that the text can actually wrap around it and so that the empty space above it is out of the view.

Playing around with it though, not sure how user-friendly the constantly shifting text is.

```js
document.querySelector('.wrapper').addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
    e.target.querySelector('.read').style.marginTop = `${e.target.scrollTop + 10}px`;
});
```

```css
.read {
  float: right;
  margin: 10px 20px 10px;
  padding: 8px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.wrapper {
  max-height: 8em;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="read" id="read">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <label for="read">Read</label>
  </div>
    Hello World Hello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello World Hello World Hello World Hello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello World Hello World Hello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello World Hello World Hello
    World Hello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello World Hello World Hello World Hello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello World Hello World HelloWorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello World Hello World Hello
    World Hello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello World Hello World Hello World Hello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello World Hello World HelloWorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello World Hello World Hello
    World Hello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello World Hello World Hello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello World Hello World Hello World HelloWorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello World Hello World Hello
    World
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this great solution. I'm going to wait a bit if anyone can come up with a solution that works at the bottom too.

Comment: I agree with @Anton Podolsky, this will be very bad idea from user experience point of view. Imagin someone trying to read the text, and every time they scroll they will lose there position and have to look around to see where there ware.  In my opinion, you should change the UI. Maybe put a big padding-right on the text so all letters are far from the checkbox, but you can still scroll. Or just put the checkbox under the textarea. Or maybe the checkbox can show only when you hover. Basically anything but please do not make your user read shifting text :D

Comment: @Nikola.grancharov To be honest I wasn't even thinking of this problem when I asked this question. In the end I decided for a solution where I added a padding to the text so that it doesn't run into the checkbox. But still this answer solved the original problem, where I didn't even think it would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

For me it is not possible to do this because the text should at all times move because of the scroll, I think it can be done with a js script but it is not possible when the div is absolute.

An alternative (creative) workaround might be to hide the checkbox when you don't mouse over it:

*I put the checkbox in red to make it show more when it is not active

```js
const read = document.querySelector('.read');
    
    read.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
      read.style.transition = "opacity 0.5s";
      read.style.opacity = 1;
    });
    
    read.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
      read.style.transition = "opacity 0.5s";
      read.style.opacity = 0.15;
    });
    
    read.style.opacity = 0.1;
    read.style.transition = "opacity 0.5s";
```

```css
.text {
      max-height: 8em;
      overflow-y: auto;
    }
    
    .read {
      display: inline;
      padding: 8px;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 5px;
      right: 40px;
      background: red;
    color:#fff;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
    
    .wrapper {
      position: relative;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="text"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer eu efficitur nunc. Suspendisse commodo condimentum felis et volutpat. Phasellus ultricies justo dolor, at porttitor ligula ornare vel. In eu nulla ut justo feugiat tincidunt. Vestibulum dignissim interdum purus, pellentesque placerat magna malesuada nec. Morbi malesuada orci non purus volutpat, ut accumsan nunc accumsan. Suspendisse posuere imperdiet diam blandit interdum. Mauris at ipsum purus. Quisque a augue nec enim mattis sagittis vel quis dui. Morbi condimentum nibh tellus, nec fermentum massa pretium suscipit. Duis dapibus ultrices dolor. Vivamus condimentum nulla nec fermentum vulputate. Cras aliquet diam in nulla euismod fringilla. Ut ultricies venenatis maximus.
    Sed luctus egestas elit ut venenatis. Sed at viverra mi. Etiam nec magna vel odio dignissim consequat. Pellentesque tempor, eros a semper accumsan, ipsum odio fringilla risus, in lacinia lorem felis quis nulla. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Vivamus tristique diam non justo dapibus elementum. Suspendisse sit amet libero a odio venenatis finibus. Curabitur ac purus sed nunc efficitur finibus. Duis vel purus sit amet nisl sollicitudin lobortis.
    Donec varius dui non maximus bibendum. Donec laoreet, elit ac eleifend dictum, velit arcu viverra sem, vehicula euismod massa justo ut massa. Pellentesque sit amet dui viverra, mattis quam at, aliquam orci. Sed nunc nunc, varius eu mollis et, eleifend a eros. Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce bibendum elit eget nunc mollis faucibus. Nam tempus euismod nisl, eget tincidunt tellus pulvinar vel. Nullam sed odio in turpis vehicula volutpat. Vestibulum a gravida arcu. Maecenas sit amet mattis diam.
    Curabitur risus est, blandit sed tempor in, molestie ut odio. Curabitur laoreet faucibus tristique. Maecenas efficitur ligula purus, ac sollicitudin turpis molestie ut. Proin vitae diam eget mi consequat posuere. In suscipit sed velit non egestas. Donec dictum dolor at libero posuere convallis. Integer orci enim, feugiat a tempor id, placerat vitae quam. Curabitur quis vestibulum purus, facilisis bibendum felis. Etiam ipsum arcu, pretium ac turpis vel, bibendum faucibus libero. Nam quis sagittis nisl. Suspendisse ultricies neque sit amet dolor faucibus, at maximus mi posuere. Aliquam vitae ornare sem, in interdum nibh. Praesent non laoreet magna. Curabitur sollicitudin faucibus sem in tincidunt.
    Aenean lacinia consequat condimentum. Vestibulum condimentum nibh ac vulputate semper. Aliquam in mauris at tortor eleifend luctus. Phasellus euismod ut nibh nec tristique. In eu urna eros. Mauris malesuada id augue accumsan auctor. Mauris congue lacus eu congue sagittis. Praesent ac sapien nulla. Pellentesque eu velit ut ipsum pharetra fermentum. Fusce condimentum sagittis ultrices. Pellentesque imperdiet enim sed ornare tempor. Fusce ultrices feugiat vestibulum. Integer massa massa, blandit ac luctus at, faucibus nec augue. Sed malesuada commodo dolor eu dictum.</p></div>
    
    <div class="read" id="read">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <label for="read">Read</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

The simplest alternative might be to leave a blank space. (I know, it's not the best). Just change the css like this:

```
.text {max-height: 10em;overflow-y: auto;padding-right: 120px;}
```

Comment: As the checkbox is the main action for the user it should not be transparent. I already thought of a similar solution where I would hide the checkbox whenever the user clicked it in order to show the full text. These both are however not really solving the underlying issue properly.