# How to have a float:right element with a text block without the text overlapping on it in bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I am new to web development. I want achieve something like this.

[image]

Here, the "Edit" portion can be of any width and the text block can be of any height. Irrespective of any height or width, I want to keep the layout the same.

I have tried something like this

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-group-sm">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="text" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Address</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8 clearfix">
        <?php if($condition) { ?> 
        <span class="settings">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>Edit
        </span>
        <?php } ?>
        <label class="form-control-static">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur tristique elit ac dolor elementum sit amet tempus ante euismod. Aenean quis enim urna, non pulvinar nunc. Aenean in varius elit. Vestibulum sed mollis tellus. Nullam id magna ligula, quis elementum turpis. Morbi felis felis, vestibulum dictum mattis commodo, suscipit et nunc. Fusce in semper nisi. Vivamus et sem velit, sed sagittis turpis. Aenean sollicitudin elit sed eros posuere id vehicula ipsum tristique. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi diam odio, tempus sed sollicitudin eu, ullamcorper ullamcorper erat. Nullam tortor dolor, porttitor eget feugiat nec, aliquet non orci. Integer eros risus, luctus in mollis quis, scelerisque quis odio. Fusce vehicula sagittis justo, sit amet mollis sem adipiscing a. Sed semper, dui sed convallis interdum, libero felis posuere est, at pulvinar orci felis et lectus.</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.form-control-static{word-wrap: break-word;}
.settings{
    float: right;
    padding: 7px 0 7px 3px;
}
```

I do not want to fix height or width of any element as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301719/prevent-absolutely-positioned-elements-from-overlapping-with-text) since my layout is responsive. Checkout my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chandannadig/u83gse13/2/) and please update it if possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you wrapping your label copy within a second label?

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the fiddle.Were you trying to achieve that.Check them.

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-group-sm">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="text" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Address</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8 clearfix">
   <label class="form-control-static">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right">edit</button>
     Lorem ipsum    
   </label>
  </div>
 </div>
```

**UPDATED FIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/u83gse13/5/

Comment: This is exactly what I did too. I wanted to update the fiddle but my internet was not working properly since today morning (happens a lot in India). I also removed class .form-control-static since my BS3 css file had a fixed height of 30px defined for this class. I still don't understand why <label> behaved that way though... any idea !! feels so silly now after I spent an entire day thinking I was trying something impossible when it was so trivial.....thanks for your valuable time man :-) cheers

Comment: Hey, I have one more major issue. Please see my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29350317/jquery-isotope-masonry-layout-leaves-gap-between-elements-in-bootstrap-3 here. Hope I'm not  asking for too much